# Trying to build an iOS library with iPhone5 (armv7s) support

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, armv7

I'm trying to build [Unrar4iOS](https://github.com/ararog/Unrar4iOS) with iPhone 5 support. I've modified both the targets and projects to have the following configurations:

[image: Project]
[image: Target]

Which I believe should generate a library that has armv7, armv7s and armv6 support. However once the .a file is built, if I do a `file libUnrar4iOS.a`

I get the following:

```
libUnrar4iOS.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
libUnrar4iOS.a (for architecture armv7):    current ar archive random library
libUnrar4iOS.a (for architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)): current ar archive random library
```

Which seems to only have `armv7` (and if I try to link to the generated framework, I get an error that there is no armv7s slice).

Am I incorrect in thinking that this should build the .a file with all three architectures?

Comment: armv7s is the CPU type 12, subtype 11. Xcode 4.5 won't compile armv6 for you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mattjgalloway mentioned above, architecture cputype (12) cpusubtype (11) IS armv7s.